# Exposing protocol-buffers interfaces

Tags: interface, protocol-buffers

I am building a distributed system which consist of modules/application with interfaces defined by protobuf messages.

Is it a good idea to expose those protobuf messages to a client directly? ... or maybe it's better to prepare a shared library which will be responsible for translation of (let's assume) method based interface to a protobuf based for each module and clients won't be aware about protobuf at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's neither a "good idea" nor a bad one. It depends on whether or not *you* want to impose protocol buffers onto your consumers. A large part of that decision is, then:

- Who are your consumers? Do you mind exposing the protobuf specifics to them?
- Will the clients be written in languages which have protobuf support?

My $0.02 is that this is a perfect use case for Protocol Buffers, since they were specifically designed with cross-system, cross-language interchange in mind. The `.proto` file makes for a concise, language-independent, thorough description of the data format. Of course, there are other similar/competing formats & libraries out there to consider (see: [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/), [Cap'n Proto](http://kentonv.github.io/capnproto/), [etc.](https://code.google.com/p/thrift-protobuf-compare/wiki/Benchmarking)) if you decide to head down this path.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to define interfaces that take Google Protobuf message classes as arguments than according to [this](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/source/browse/tags/2.5.0/README.txt#123) and [that](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/source/browse/tags/2.5.0/vsprojects/readme.txt#28) section in Google's Protobuf documentation it is not a good idea to expose Protobuf messages to a client directly. In short, with every version of Protobuf the generated code is likely to be not binary compatible with older code. So don't do it!

However, if you are planning to define interfaces that take byte arrays containing serialized Protobuf messages as function/method parameters then I totally agree with Matt Ball's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15993288/721095).